# DDMathParser - How to recognize an error is iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, parsing

I'm building an app that graph a text given function using DDMathParser by Dave DeLong. I need to know (for every "x" I evaluate) if the solution exist, or it just gives me 0.00 because it couldn't evaluate it. Maybe a Bool?

```
while (x <= (viewWidth - originOffsetX)/axisLenghtX) {

        NSDictionary *variableSubstitutions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x] forKey:@"x"];
        NSString *solution = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[DDMathEvaluator sharedMathEvaluator] 
                                                               evaluateString:plotterExpression withSubstitutions:variableSubstitutions]];
        numericSolution = solution.numberByEvaluatingString.doubleValue;
        NSLog(@"%f", numericSolution);
        if (newline) {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(curveContext, (x*axisLenghtX + originOffsetX), (-numericSolution * axisLenghtY + originOffsetY));
            newline = FALSE;
        } else {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(curveContext, (x*axisLenghtX + originOffsetX), (-numericSolution * axisLenghtY + originOffsetY));
        }
        x += dx;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since you're using the simplest API possible, there's no way to by notified if there's an error.  This is clearly explained in the first section of the [Usage](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Usage) page on the wiki:

> There are several ways to evaluate strings, depending on how much
>   customization you want to do. Most of these options require an NSError
>   ** parameter, although some do not.
>
> - If you use one of the options that does not accept an NSError **, then
>     any tokenization, parsing, or evaluation errors will be NSLogged.
> - If you use one of the options that does accept an NSError **, then you
>     must supply one. Failing to do so will probably result in a crash.

So what you want to do is this:

```
NSDictionary *variableSubstitutions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble:x] forKey:@"x"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSNumber *number = [[DDMathEvaluator sharedMathEvaluator] evaluateString:plotterExpression withSubstitutions:variableSubstitutions error:&error]];

if (number == nil) {
  NSLog(@"an error occurred while parsing: %@", error);
} else {
  numericSolution = [number doubleValue];
  // continue on normally
}
```